# Overzealous deletion of comments

Tags: discussion, moderation, comments

I am writing about chx's answer at https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/89766/19400.

A user asked whether pat-downs are to be conducted by officers of the same sex as the passenger being searched.  I responded with a comment, pinging the user.  A few seconds later, chx edited his answer to include the relevant sentence in the quoted material.

At that point, I considered deleting my comment, but decided to let it stand, since the ping should, by inviting the user to revisit the answer, inform the user that the request for clarification has received a response.

Now I see that the comments have been deleted, presumably by a moderator.

I find this sort of thing very frustrating.  Sure, those comments are not critical to the answer, but they do provide context for the edit, and they shed light on people's thoughts about the subject under discussion.

Furthermore, what does it cost to leave those comments in place?  What benefit is achieved by removing them?

Comment: Define "overzealous".  Comment threads are subject to drift, and when the drift turns to ad hominem content or let's-shoot-the-messenger or pugnacious attention to trivial detail or have reached then end of what can be productive, then moderator intervention is the solution.

Comment: @GayotFow none of that happened here.

Answer (score 4):

I'm the mod who deleted your comment.

Comments are second-class citizens on Travel.SE and as such they can be removed at any time, especially if they've been addressed already. I understand it might be irritating and would avoid touching recent comments in the future.

Comment: This is not what should happen. Please don't. Just because one person complains.

Comment: @chx I think it's good to find balance

Comment: @GayotFow comments would still be deleted, just not 5 minutes after they're posted

Answer (score -3):

https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

> #### When shouldn't I comment?
>
> Comments are not recommended for any of the following:
>
> - Suggesting corrections that don't fundamentally change the meaning of
>     the post; instead, make or suggest an edit;

Comment: This does not answer my question.

Comment: I mean: the comment shouldn't have existed in the first place.

Comment: Which one, mine or the one to which I was responding?

Comment: Yours. You should've edited the answer.

Comment: I thought the original comment merited a direct response. What's the point of the ping feature if not that?